# How do I prevent my text area (excually input type email) from not being filled

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have form. Form include name,lastname,email,phone etc. If anybody submit the form without filling email adress my database record this email adress in blank. After this situation if this situation repeat, warning message: same email adress.  (First email adress =>blank   Second email adress => blank)  I want to use regex. Users have to fill email adress. But I could not found any examples. Thanks to much.

Please have a look at the related code:

```
if (userExists.equals("")) {
    bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "Lütfen email adresinizi giriniz.");
}

if (userExists != null) {
    bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "Verilen e-postayla kayıtlı bir kullanıcı var");
}
```

Comment: /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/   is not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why is this question java-tagged?

Comment: Because I am codding java. maybe somebody help me different way. (not regex)

Comment: OK, you can use regular expressions in Java, too... But please show us your effort.

Comment: actually my problem like that.  if (userExists.equals("")) {
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "Lütfen email adresinizi giriniz.");
        }
        if (userExists != null) {
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "Verilen e-postayla  kayıtlı bir kullanıcı var");
        }

Comment: second if always working.

Comment: What do you mean by *second if always working*? Why do you `rejectValue` if `userExists != null`? Could you please add some more information on that?

Answer (score 0):

How about some JavaScript validation code perhaps something like this which doesn't let the form actually submit if the Email field is blank:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--
    function jsValidatePg() {
        // Dim var.
        var strValid;

        // Init.
        strValid = "";

        // Set var.
        if (document.frmMain.Email.value == "") {
            strValid = "The Email field must be filled in.";
        }

        // Determine if valid.
        if (strValid == "") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert(strValid);
            return false;
        }
    }
//-->
</script>

<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain" action="mypage2.asp" method="post">

<input type="text" name="FirstName" size="15" maxlength="25" value="">
<input type="text" name="LastName" size="15" maxlength="25" value="">
<input type="text" name="Email" size="15" maxlength="25" value="">
<input type="text" name="Phone" size="15" maxlength="25" value="">

<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onClick="return jsValidatePg();">
```